# How can I use Parallel.ForEach for Excel?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, parallel.foreach

I am trying to use Parallel.ForEach for Excel but I get error. the code is

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public void function(Excel.Range range)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(range, item=>
    {
        //do stuff
    });
}
```

Error is *Error 7: The type arguments for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Action)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.*

If you have any idea, I will appreciate very much.

Comment: There is no idea to use Excel from several threads. Excel is single threaded (COM STA) so all calls will be marshalled to the same thread anyway.

Comment: @adrianm, I suggest you convert that into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The error you're seeing is because `Parallel.ForEach` isn't supported on non-generic collections.

From the [Parallel Programming in .NET blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/03/02/9971804.aspx):

> .NET 2.0 introduced Generics to allow enhanced code reusability and
>   type safety.  Since then, generic collections (IEnumerable,
>   List, Dictionary, etc.) have become standard and are recommended
>   over their non-generic counterparts (IEnumerable, ArrayList,
>   HashTable, etc.).  **As a result, Parallel.ForEach only supports generic
>   collections**, so code like the following will fail to compile.

There is a workaround, using `IEnumerable.Cast` as they mention in the blog:

```
Parallel.ForEach(r.Cast<object>(), _ =>
{
    // Do stuff
});
```

Though this will *compile*, it will **not work** with `Excel.Range` as it has thread affinity and will only work via a STA thread, as it is doing COM interop.